# Draw SVG to canvas on image load causes crash

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js, canvas, svg

I have a d3.js visualization and want to output the created SVG as a PNG on the client.  I have been able to do this in the past by drawing the SVG to a canvas then converting the canvas to a blob.  This was works properly in FF, but causes Chrome to crash. `console.log(image)` and `console.log(this)` in the crash both print blank lines in the Chrome console and `ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0)` seems to be causing the crash ('done drawing' does not get printed).  However, if I put a break point right before or on `ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0)`, everything works fine and nothing crashes. Is this somehow a race condition in Chrome, or unable to access the image variable inside the load event?

**Edit 1:** Added a completed fiddle.  The svg/xml string is hardcoded because the code that generates the svg depends on a secure server. Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)

https://jsfiddle.net/weeser/ngup768m/

Comment: Which version of chrome ? They did taint the canvas when an svg image was drawn to it from a blob. A dataURI worked however. Also, when creating your blob, you don't need the encoding in the type. (a minimal **Complete** and reproducible code would be great for us to help you)

Comment: If Chrome crashes, report it to [Chrome's bugtracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list)

Comment: Not sure if you should file a bug, this seems to be fixed in Canary 59. And for a workaround for 56, just use a dataURI as I said in my first comment : https://jsfiddle.net/Kaiido/m19mgxv5/

Comment: Thank you @Kaiido, the data URI looks to be a good workaround for the issue.